# Ubuntu Touch: 12 hour clock not available

Tags: ubuntu-touch, clock

My language is set to Dutch but there is no option to set the clock to 12 hour mode (AM/PM). On Ubuntu Desktop the option is there. Is there any way to accomplish this? I do not mind fiddling in the terminal or whatever.

Comment: It's a known issue. Developers are working on it. You may follow this bug report http://pad.lv/1392699

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully OTA-11 will fix this. Or there will be a workaround in the meantime...